# Should the `windows` tag be used in conjunction with a tag of better specificity?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I've seen a lot of questions tagged with both [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) and a more specific tag such as [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7), [windows-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8), [windows-8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8.1), or [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10).

However in the description of [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows), it clearly says:

> For issues **not specific to a single version** of Microsoft Windows. Otherwise, use a more specific tag (...)

Should these questions be re-tagged to remove the general [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag because there is a more specific tag? Or is there a consensus that the excerpt is incorrect and this is a fine practice?

Comment: As far as I understand it (and I was the last one to edit the tag), using both [windows] and a more specific tag at the same time isn't exactly correct practice. It's okay to edit [windows] out in this case.

Comment: @DragonLord Oooooh Noooo. I'm close to getting my **first** gold tag badge in Windows :(

Comment: I believe that you should (of course) always use the specific tag for the version that you're using, ***but also*** use the generic [windows] tag unless you're sure that the problem is unique to that version.

Comment: Seems like we have a conflicting opinion. Either remove the [tag:windows] from questions with another specific tag, or add the [tag:windows] to questions without it that also have a specific tag (as per Scott). I'm actually not sure which would be best.

Comment: @DavidPostill "close to getting my first gold tag badge in Windows"  [One of us! One of us! One of us!](https://youtu.be/1Y_KNYNzN6A?t=5s)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 LOL ;)

Comment: @Insane: there is people that searches posts with tag and keywords. When we delete a tag the same research will not give any more that post in the answer... and we obtain the opposite effect. We should be cautious when we delete a tag, and even when we retag an old question _"well visited"_. It is [suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/282051) even simply to merge with _caution_...

Answer (score 10):

**Good Practice When Writing a Question**

The tag wiki is accurate.  Version-specific tags are for issues that don't apply to all versions, or questions about a specific version.  In those cases, the version-specific tag is important information about the nature of the problem.  If the problem is version-specific, adding the version-agnostic tag is just confusing and defeats the purpose.

- Questions about a problem concerning, or specific to, one version: use just that version tag.

  How do I do XYZ in Win XP?
  I just installed Win 10 and nothing works anymore.
- Questions about a problem or feature that applies just to a range of versions, like something introduced in Win 8 that also applies to 8.1, and you know that the issue applies to several versions: include the applicable version tags.  It could be helpful to others searching for a solution.
- Questions where you don't know whether your problem is version-specific:  use the version-agnostic tag and mention your version in the question.  However, this is a case where nothing would be lost in including both tags.
- Generic question that applies to all versions (or at least all non-ancient versions): use just the version-agnostic tag.  Adding a version-specific tag just confuses things.

It's generally a good idea to mention the installed version within the question.

**Retagging an Existing Question**

- If better tags will help the question get answered, or help future searchers find it, retag it.
- If better tags won't make a difference, don't bump the question just to perfect the tags.  This would include new questions where the tags are "good enough", and old questions that have already been well answered despite "sub-optimal" tags.

Comment: I like this answer. It covers all the possibilities together with clear explanations.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you